# My mom is experiencing strong vertigo

Tags: dizziness, vertigo

My mom had 2 episodes of severe vertigo in the last 2 weeks. First one started one morning, and she had to lay in bed for 3-4 hours before it subsided, it kept spinning even when she's lying in bed and not moving.

The 2nd one started during the day when she leaned forward to pick somethign up and felt everything spinning around her. It went away when she keeps her head up, but as soon as her head tilted or leaned forward it would trigger an attack, and each attack lasted for 30 sec -1 min each. And she also felt nauseas during the 2nd one for an entire day. But as long as she keeps her head up without moving the verigo went away, which was not the case in during the first one.

There's NO report of ear ringing or fullness sensation either time.

In addition, 2 years ago she had a similar vertigo attack in which she fainted and woke up after a couple of minutes. There was no fainting in the most recent 2 attacks.

She's 65.

What can it be and what can be done about it?

Comment: Welcome to Health. We cannot give you personal medical advise for [many reasons](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), but we can help you rephrase your question to make it more general and thus adhere to the scope if that is in your interest.

Comment: @Narusan Thanks. Please do.

Comment: The trouble is that to rephrase it one would have to change so much, that the system won't let me do it, only the OP (the owner of the post). If you ask what causes vertigo and how it can be dealt with without invoking personal information.

Comment: It's a request for a diagnosis that we couldn't provide even if we wanted to. She needs to see a physician. I don't see any way to salvage it so voting to close.

Comment: The doctor has to investigate, but it's good to keep in mind that the most likely cause is [this](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/vertigo/basics/definition/con-20028216), which is not serious. This is not a substitute to go to the doctor, just to not be a priori stressed out about this. The doctor has to be consulted because there is always the possibility that a complaint like this does turn out to be a more serious problem, but what you don't want to do is make that assumption right from the start.

Comment: @CountIblis Fainting isn't a symptom of BPPV. That's an alarming symptom that needed to be investigated at the time and still does. She needs a physicians, not stackexchange.

Comment: @CareyGregory I agree, she needs to go to the doctor, but being stressed out about this doesn't help. When I had  dizzy spells after an accident, that always triggered a shock reaction. I wasn't afraid, but it would make me reach out to my desk and hold it firmly in a shock reaction, the heart rate was immediately raised. I didn't faint, but I can imagine that at age 65 and not being anywhere near my current fitness level, such a reaction could well cause fainting.

Comment: @CountIblis Fainting and then not regaining consciousness "for a couple of minutes" isn't due to vertigo.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks, I made her perform the head turning maneuvre at home and now the vertigo is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Your mother should see an ENT (ear, nose, throat specialist).  Vertigo is often recurring and treatable.  My mother also suffers from it and she was reluctant to take it seriously and kept saying her ears felt fine.  I finally got her to ask for a referral to an ENT last year and it has been life changing.

Her episodes were getting more frequent and intense and her medication wasn't helping like it used to.  She says now she wishes she had gone ages ago.  The Dr helps her with adjustments and then gives her exercises to do at home as well.  She too (my mother) has no ear sensations that she is aware of, but that makes no difference really.  After seeing the tremendous difference it was in her life to see the ENT, it would be the first place I would go if I were having those symptoms.  If it's not ear related, they can also determine *that* as well and suggest what she needs to look into next.

No one should just live with vertigo attacks and it can be very dangerous (think of one coming on while driving, on stairs, etc).  Even one attack a month can cripple your life if you can't even say when it's coming.  My mother was stubborn and it took her becoming desperate to seek proper help.  She was in bed often at that time and loosing weight due to nausea (she kept telling me she was "taking a nap").

The final straw for her was me telling her she was not permitted to babysit my children or take them anywhere.  She was so hurt and angry, but she was here visiting one day when it hit, and she passed out right in front of me and then tried to argue with me that she hadn't lost consciousness.  One trip to the ENT made such a difference, just one.  It only got better from there.  She had to be suffering more than she said because she looks amazing now.  Her color is better, she looks healthier on the whole, she has more energy.  Vertigo can be life altering.  I would always encourage all people get help and get it early on.